# Tooltip is not showing properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, tooltip

I am new to `WPF`. I want to show custom tool tip when a error occurs in `TextBox`. So I have used `Style` as shown below:

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">                   
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip Placement="Top">                            
                            <Border Margin="-4,0,-4,-3" Padding="2" Background="Red">
                                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect></OuterGlowBitmapEffect>
                                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                                <Label Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"></Label>
                            </Border>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Above code is not showing error message in `ToolTip`. Could you please help m ein this regard? Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your current style with the following style ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation)):

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>  
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And you should create style for `ToolTip`:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border Name="Border" Margin="-4,0,-4,-3" Padding="2" Background="Red">
                    <Border.BitmapEffect>
                        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect></OuterGlowBitmapEffect>
                    </Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Margin="4" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        TextElement.Foreground="White" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"                                      
                        />                                    
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example of usage:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"                     
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also replace

```
Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent
```

with

```
Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}
```

because in your case you'll get an silent ArgumentOutOfRangeException when there are no validation errors. Don't forget to implement IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo.